Intereseting property of factorials: does some $n!$ end in $2^{2024}$ if we skip the zeros at the end?
I came up with the following problem:

Is there, for any natural $a$, an $n!$ ending with $2^a$ (if we skip the ending zeros). For example, for $a=10$ we have $49!= 6...921\underline{1024}0 \ldots 000$.


I am not sure if $n!$ can end on any sequence we desire so I tried using modular arithmetic instead. I want, for any natural $a$, to find an $n$ such that $$\frac{n!}{10^{v_5(n!)}}\equiv2^a \mod 10^b$$ where $b=\lfloor a \log2\rfloor +2$. We can rewrite this congruence as two different congruences:
\begin{align}\frac{n!}{10^{v_5(n!)}} \equiv 2^{a} \equiv 0\mod{2^b} \iff \boxed{v_2(n!)-v_5(n!)\ge b} && (1)\end{align} since, for $a\ge3$, we have $a>b$. The other modular equation is \begin{align}\frac{n!}{10^{v_5(n!)}} \equiv 2^{a} \mod{5^b} \iff \frac{n!}{5^{v_5(n!)}} \equiv 2^{a+v_5(n!)}  \mod{5^b} && (2)\end{align} Note that for $(1)$ we have a nice restriction on $n$; however, I am not sure how to satisfy equation $(2)$.
I came up with the following lemma, which is a direct consequence of any number coprime with $m$ having a unique inverse mod $m$: let $\{r_1,\ldots,r_{\phi(n)}\}$ be a reduced residue system mod $m$, then $$\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}r_i^2\equiv1\mod m$$ since we can pair each element with its inverse (even if it is itself). Then I tried to force $2\times 5^b \mid n$ to ensure that $n!/5^{v_5(n!)}$ has an even number of reduced residues systems since the denominator cancels all fives out of the numerator; nevetheless, this doesn't seem to work since we aren't actually erasing all numbers which used to be multiples of five in the numerator (for example, $15$ becomes $3$ after dividing $n!$ by $5^{v_5(n!)}$ and that $3$ never cancels out so we can't apply the lemma). If I could make $n!/5^{v_5(n!)}$
congruent to $1$ mod $5^b$ then I can impose the condition $\phi(5^b) \mid a+v_5(n!)$ to find an $n$ that satisfies the initial congruence.
I would appreciate any help, thanks beforehand.

Have you ever heard of the Legendre-de Polignac formula? It might help.

Yeah, I have, it would be useful to ensure $\phi(5^b) \mid a + v_5(n!)$ but I don't see how it helps with the other equation.
